# SQL: extracting userIDs that performed an action

Tags: mysql, sql

Apologies for the question title, but don't know what function could achieve what I need.

For simplicity, I have below table:

```
UserID  | date     | action
----------------------------
1       | 1/1/2015 | 
2       | 1/1/2015 | 
2       | 2/1/2015 | 
2       | 3/1/2015 | 
2       | 4/1/2015 | sale
3       | 2/1/2015 | 
3       | 4/1/2015 |
4       | 5/1/2015 | 
4       | 7/1/2015 | sale
5       | 3/1/2015 | sale
6       | 4/1/2015 |
7       | 9/1/2015 | sale
```

I would like to be able to run a query where I will exclude all UserIDs which didn't end up with any action.

Therefore I would expect to see this:

```
UserID  | date     | action
----------------------------
2       | 1/1/2015 | 
2       | 2/1/2015 | 
2       | 3/1/2015 | 
2       | 4/1/2015 | sale
4       | 5/1/2015 | 
4       | 7/1/2015 | sale
5       | 3/1/2015 | sale
7       | 9/1/2015 | sale
```

Is this something that can be done in SQL?

Comment: `select * from table where UserID in (select UserID from table where action is not Null)`

Comment: @TZHX. More acute will be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE UserID IN (SELECT **DISTINCT** UserID FROM table WHERE action IS NOT NULL)`.

Comment: @cFreed I would have thought the query optimiser would take care of that. But I'm not a regular MySQL user.

Comment: @TZHX. Hmm... I didn't think to that: maybe you're right.

Comment: Sorry but your suggestion didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the blanks in the action column are NULL, you can write this way:

```
SELECT
    u.UserID,
    u.date,
    u.action
FROM
    (SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE action IS NOT NULL GROUP BY UserID) action_user
JOIN
    users u ON u.UserID = action_user.UserId
```

If it's actually a blank value, you would update the criteria in the subquery action_user to WHERE u.action != ''

If your DB Engine supports EXISTS, you could use that for better readability: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php.  Avoid IN/NOT IN for sub queries that reference many rows, as that often results in a RBAR (row by row) execution with poor performance.  IN/NOT IN are typically reserved for a specific set of values as opposed to a subquery.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/884dd/3

Comment: @vanalee1987 thank you for your query (still testing, I have 1.2gb DB so it will take time. To increase performance, as per your suggestion, I am currently using local server (XAMPP) with MySQL. If that helps, what modifications would you use here to speed up the query?

Comment: I would put a clustered index on your user table if one does not already exist.  Possibly add a secondary index on action if the tables are quite large.

Comment: Will do! Still running though.

Comment: Just quick possible modification. If I would like to add small filter on the data, for example to print only data that resulted in sale between 7th-9th, including touch points leading to sale but only for the ones that resulted in sale in specified time period.

Comment: If you are short on memory, you might try storing the subquery in a temp table (stores on disk instead of memory) and then running the query:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS action_user AS (SELECT UserID FROM users u WHERE u.action IS NOT NULL GROUP BY UserID);

SELECT
 u.UserID,
 u.date,
 u.action
FROM
 action_user
JOIN
 users u ON u.UserID = action_user.UserId

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE action_user;

Comment: Please look at the comments under the question: what do you think about DISTINCT in the subquery? Is it needed, or be automatically optimized?

Comment: Yeah, if there is additional filtering you can do in the subquery, that will improve performance.  In example:
(SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE action IS NOT NULL AND date >= '2015-07-01' AND date < '2015-10-01' GROUP BY UserID)

Comment: @cFreed, you are correct that you must specify DISTINCT or use a GROUP BY to ensure the records in the subquery are unique and do not result in unintended duplicates.

Edit: This is not required when using WHERE IN as it is not part of a JOIN.

Comment: @cFreed, actually, that is not the case if using the IN clause in the example above.  IN will not cause duplicates if DISTINCT is not specified.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. But now I'm incertain: since it doesn't use IN, wouldn't be DISTINCT added to your current answer?

Comment: No worries, the GROUP BY handles this.  IE, SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table is equivalent to SELECT column FROM table GROUP BY column.

Comment: @Chriser, are you certain you need all the records in the output of your question?  Or do you just need users that had a sale action during a time period?  IE, SELECT userID FROM users WHERE action = 'Sale' AND date >= '2015-07-01' AND date < '2015-10-01'

Comment: Hi guys. I've tried your methods and unfortunately none worked. I've build quick table based on my example and nothing worked, can you confirm that it is working your end?

Comment: This worked!! SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID IN (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM users WHERE action <>'')

Comment: Perfect!  I had an alias out of place, and added a SQL fiddle, but looks like you are probably good to go if that's working for you :-)

Comment: Ah, and yeah, you have blanks instead of NULLS which might have been the cause.  Glad you got it working, cheers!